# Launching external text editors from the Rstudio editing window

Tags: vim, rstudio, autohotkey

While the native text editor native to RStudio is usable, its Vim mappings are still not ideal. Thus, is there a function/command in RStudio that can summon an external text editor? The ideal manner would be a keyboard shortcut that triggers "external editor", which is specified through the setting.

There is an out-dated request as the following:

- https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200662936-Editor-link-to-external-editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own.  Use `rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path` to get the name of the current document in the source editor.  This page: https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/ describes how to attach some R code to a key.

For example, you might put this function in your add-in:

```
editInTextedit <- function() 
  system(paste("open -e", rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path))
```

and (on a Mac) it would run `textedit` to edit the current file.  Or, if you are in a new enough version of RStudio with the Terminal built in, you could use

```
editInVim <- function()
  rstudioapi::terminalExecute(paste("vim", rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path))
```

I find the vim I get there doesn't work very well (it doesn't understand arrow keys, for instance), but you might have better luck.

Edited to add:  Add-ins are stored in R packages.  To make the two functions above into add-ins, create a new project and choose to create a new R package.  Give it some name that won't conflict with other R packages, e.g. "AddInEditors".  Put those two function definitions into a .R file in the R subdirectory, and also create the file `inst/rstudio/addins.dcf` containing

```
Name: Run Textedit
Description: Runs Textedit on the current source file.
Binding: editInTextedit
Interactive: true

Name: Run Vim
Description: Runs Vim on the current source file.
Binding: editInVim
Interactive: true
```

Then run `Build | Install and restart` on the package, and the addins should be available.

That doesn't attach them to hot keys; see the previous reference for instructions on that.  Without hot keys you can get to them in the `Addins` menu on the top menu bar, or via `Tools | Addins | Browse addins...`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for pointing out the addins approach, yet I am confused at "where and how to put these functions/addins"? The official site said something like "Create a file at `inst/rstudio/addins.dcf`", yet this is suggested to be used as a relative path w.r.t. to the specific project. (Ref: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/208887987-Registering-Addins); Question: how am I going to enable the addins you are suggesting at the global level? By dropping some function (not sure about the format yet) to my home folder? May you please clarify :)

Comment: I added more instructions.

Comment: Hi, this is amazing! I just want to add that, in order to change a shortcut, one need to click on the "invisible box" in the shortcut column. Also, the four lines of R functions should go to the `~/AddInEditors/R/Function.R` (R subdirectory).

Comment: A few more observations: 1. that I shall invoke a new terminal every single time that I run the `editInVim` function (well, I cam calling `gvim` specifically, which is the GUI version of Vim). This creates a lot of buffers/terminal-sessions in RStudio. 2. on another machine, while I have no trouble calling `gvim` directly from the Terminal, I shall get the following error messages from Git-Bash (same across two machines): `'gvim' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[Process completed]
[Exit code: 1]`